# Residue from biomass incineration

Tags: organic-oxidation

What gasses are typically produced when biomass is incinerated at high temperatures (600 C) in high oxygen environments and what is a typical composition of the ashes left behind?

Comment: Google is your friend. I found this in seconds  https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Chemical-composition-of-wood-ash-from-various-species-of-timber-14_tbl1_270163491

Comment: This is only the ash, not gasses released. It's also specific to wood ash, how similar is wood ash to say food waste or other biomass that's burnt?